# How can I update a text object dynamically in the Blender Game Engine?

Tags: scripting, game-engine, logic-bricks

I have seen examples of HUD's showing a dynamic count of either ammunition or objects. I have the general idea of what I want, but I need to know how to update a text object dynamically in the game engine. My use case would be like so: `on [collide with collectible] update[stockpile = stockpile + 1]`.

Basically, I want to add one to a value (dynamically displayed in a text element) every time the player collides with a certain type of mesh.

Comment: do you mind using the actual text object? If so it is easy.

Comment: NoviceInDisguise? using BGE???? unheard of.

Comment: @VinceScalia lol, IKR? I'm even making a game o.O

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this using logic bricks, the following are added to the text object :

[image]

the Text object has a special property called text, i have added an integer property which is incremented by space key then it gets copied to the text property at each logic tick

here is the test play :

[image]

Comment: This is the general thing I wanted, thanks! I think I can just swap out the keyboard logic for a message sensor sent from the collectible.