# Text Properties in Blender 2.68

Tags: game-engine

I have a game that I want to use dynamic text for a Points system and a Lives system. The problem I run into is that when I create a Text Property for the dynamic text, the property name is Text - for both. I need to use logic bricks to finish what I want with points and lives, but both pieces of dynamic text are named Text ... how do I discern between the two when using the logic bricks??

Comment: even though the properties has the same names they are on different objects , how are you accessing these variables ?

Comment: the property sensor access the current object properties that's why you see only one

Comment: see if this example helps with using the text http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29253/how-can-i-update-a-text-object-dynamically-in-the-blender-game-engine

Comment: the problem occurs when an object is sending a message to Text - which Text property will it default to ... there are two??

Comment: the example is half of what we are doing - now, what if you wanted to add a Lives counter?  When you create the dynamic text for this, the Text property (by default) is text .... how will the game know if you are sending messages to the counter (like in your example) or the Lives counter when they are both labeled Text??

Comment: I know how to do a work-around ... just add a Lives 'indicator' (animated green/red lives indicator), but I would really like to know if the other can be done in Blender :-)

Comment: I really don't get the situation yet , if you can upload a sample file or add screenshots of the setup so i can understand

Comment: In this image you can see that I have 2 point systems - one for regular points and one for counting Lives.  They both must have a Text Property but the default name for both properties is Text - how do I make this work when I cannot tell Blender which Text is to receive the message??  Not sure how to add an image of this??

Comment: you can choose which object receives the message in the actuator , the text objects will definitely have different names , you add the image by editing your question and clicking the little square ( mountain image )

Comment: click "edit" under your question , then click on the small square ( next to the curly brackets ontop of the question ) then browse to your image

Comment: sorry - I don't have an image like that ... I do understand what you are saying - the Text Property is attached to two different objects - I just need to rename each of those objects ... I will look at this a bit more - still trying to get my head around it :-)

Comment: take a look at the help section of this site

Comment: Why can't you rename the object "text" to text.001 so you don't have a problem with messaging, and keep the property "text" the same?